# How to have two elements float to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created an accordion that displays job roles. On the right of the top div, there is suppose to be an image before the "x" close button. Like this:
[image]

However, so far the image comes after the "x" which is not what I want. 
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="acc">
  <div class="acc-titel">Graphic Designer - London <span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x60" alt=""></span></div>
  <div class="acc-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.acc-titel {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #08455c;
  transition: background 0.1s ease, transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #08455c;
  span{
    float: right;
    margin-top:-12px;
  }
}

.acc-titel:after {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  color: #08455c;
  float: right !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);  
}

.acc-titel:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active:after {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.acc-content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease, opacity 0.8s ease, transform 0.8s ease;
}

.acc-content p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/LBazMm

Comment: @epascarello how do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your desired output and the fact that you're using an `::after` pseudo element to create the `+`/`x` character it makes much more sense to use absolute positioning to achieve this.

You can set `top` and `right` on the icon, and then move the `img` slightly to the left by adding some `padding-right` to it so it's not conflicting. Try this:

```js
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("acc-titel");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
  accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var showContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (showContent.style.maxHeight) {
      showContent.style.maxHeight = null;
      showContent.style.opacity = null;
      showContent.style.transform = "translateY(5px)";
    } else {
      showContent.style.maxHeight = showContent.scrollHeight + "px";
      showContent.style.opacity = "1";
      showContent.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.acc-titel {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #08455c;
  transition: background 0.1s ease, transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #08455c;
}

.acc-titel span {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -12px;
  padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}

.acc-titel:after {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  color: #08455c;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.acc-titel:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active:after {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.acc-content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease, opacity 0.8s ease, transform 0.8s ease;
}

.acc-content p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="acc">
  <div class="acc-titel">Graphic Designer - London <span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x60" alt=""></span></div>
  <div class="acc-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or just put the after on the span?

Comment: Again you saved me big time. Thanks

Comment: @epascarello I tried that, but it meant that the vertical alignment of the `+` was affected.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("acc-titel");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
  accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var showContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (showContent.style.maxHeight) {
      showContent.style.maxHeight = null;
      showContent.style.opacity = null;
      showContent.style.transform = "translateY(5px)";
    } else {
      showContent.style.maxHeight = showContent.scrollHeight + "px";
      showContent.style.opacity = "1";
      showContent.style.transform = "translateY(0px)";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.acc-titel {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #08455c;
  transition: background 0.1s ease, transform 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #08455c;
  
}
.acc-titel span{
    position: absolute;
    right: 58px;
    top: 8px
}
.acc-titel:after {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 100;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  color: #08455c;
  float: right !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);  
}

.acc-titel:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active:after {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.acc-content {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease, opacity 0.8s ease, transform 0.8s ease;
}

.acc-content p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="acc">
  <div class="acc-titel">Graphic Designer - London <span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x60" alt=""></span></div>
  <div class="acc-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Position of the span holding  image was made absolute and adjusted the top and right.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this.

You should always have your HTML in correct order first, and try to solve most things that way before resorting to pseudoelements or floats.

```
<div class="acc">
  <div class="acc-titel">Graphic Designer - London <span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60x60" alt=""><i class="closeBtn">+</i></span></div>
  <div class="acc-content">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add the CSS to the i element.

```
i.closeBtn {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-style: normal;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 100;
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0.7em;
  color: #08455c;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);    
}
```

Dont use !important needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by simply specifying a "before" pesudo-element instead of "after" in your CSS, like this

```
.acc-titel:before {
    font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
    font-weight: 100;
    content: "+";
    margin-left: 20px; // Also added this to separate it from the image
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    color: #08455c;
    float: right !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 1);  
}

.active:before {
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}
```